# Can Re-write / Modify URL with javascript / Jquery after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting, client-side

Is it possible to re-write URL without reloading the page via jQuery/Javascript?

Let's say you have the following URL:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

can we append the value: `/pId=XYZ`

So you can get

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/pId=XYZ`

Is this possible?

Comment: It's very easy to do a proper formatting of your question, maybe you could do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you can change without redirecting is the hash part of url:

```
document.location.hash = "whatever";
```

Comment: Succinct. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, and you don't need jquery : simply use the History API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Beware that it's usually a little painful to handle history in a complex ajax application, as you have to handle state serialization of the pages, state loading, and so on. And you can't apply this to a badly designed site as are many ajaxified sites. And this won't work on "old" browsers like IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can, but only on browsers implementing [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4966090/3287) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5527617/3287) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9340121/3287) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7922918/3287)

Answer (score 1):

you can get the current Url with

```
var url = document.location.href;
```

then you add the part to the url

```
url += "/mySubFolder";
```

rest of my post didnt fit the question ... i should read more carefully :( !

Answer (score 0):

After encountering this problem, I think the @DenysSéguret answer is exactly what you need.

When it's supported by the browser, you can use

```
window.history.pushState(stateObj, title, url);
```

Or

```
window.history.replaceState(stateObj, title, url);
```

As stated by @DenysSéguret, you can find the documentation at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API