# How to determine if browser is supporting js pushState function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use dynamic URL update through js script:

```
window.history.pushState("string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

But if browser is old and not supporing this function it should simply redirect to new URL.

Is there any simple way to check it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966090/can-use-pushstate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest (and most performant):

```
if ('history' in window && 'pushState' in history) { // available
```

Still, I'd suggest using some established solutions for history management, like [**History.js**](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js).

Answer (score 7):

You simply check:

```
if (history.pushState) {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
try {
    window.history.pushState("string", "Title", "/new-url");
} catch ( e ) {
    window.location = "/new-url";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!!history && !!history.pushState){
   //browsers which support history and history's push state method
}
```